# How to run a particular task after 7 PM on Thursday using ScheduledExecutorsService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to schedule a job to run every Thursday after 7 PM anytime. But so far with the below code I am able to make it run on Thursday but not after 7 PM anytime.

I am using `ScheduledExecutorsService` for this. Is there any way I can make it to run after 7 PM on Thursday?

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

final ArrayList<Callable<Void>> tasks = Lists.newArrayList(new TestBImpl(), new TestAImpl());

Calendar with = Calendar.getInstance();

Map<Integer, Integer> dayToDelay = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.FRIDAY, 0);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.SATURDAY, 6);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.SUNDAY, 5);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.MONDAY, 4);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, 3);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, 2);
dayToDelay.put(Calendar.THURSDAY, 1);
int dayOfWeek = with.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int delayInDays = dayToDelay.get(dayOfWeek);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
             executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // or loggger would be better
        }
    }
}, 0, delayInDays, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Any suggestions will be of great help. I need to use Multithreaded way of executing my tasks. In my `tasks`, I will have more than two classes as right now I only have two classes which I am executing it in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I would make scheduler to run the task on each hour, the task would use Calendar to determine date and hour and execute only if it's Thursday 7 PM

```
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 19 && c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.THURSDAY) {
                try {
                    executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); // or loggger would be better
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: But it doesn't mean that it would execute my task every hour right? Sorry got little confuse with this. Can you provide an example if possible just to make my understanding clear?

Comment: The code example should check Calendar.AM_PM as well.

Comment: @Michael Easter I agree